# Issues with replacing a subset of a data.frame using the R Package dplyr

Tags: r, package, dplyr

I am trying to replace some filtered values of a data set. So far, I wrote this lines of code:

```
df %>%
  filter(group1 == uniq[i]) %>%
  mutate(values = ifelse(sum(values) < 1, 2, NA)),
```

where uniq is just a list containing variable names I want to focus on (and group1 and values are column names). This is actually working. However, it only outputs the altered filtered rows and does not replace anything in the data set df. Does anyone have an idea, where my mistake is? Thank you so much! The following code is to reproduce the example:

```
group1 <- c("A","A","A","B","B","C")
values <- c(0.6,0.3,0.1,0.2,0.8,0.9)
df = data.frame(group1, group2, values)
uniq <- unique(unlist(df$group1))

for (i in 1:length(uniq)){
  df <- df %>%
  filter(group1 == uniq[i]) %>%
    mutate(values = ifelse(sum(values) < 1, 2, NA))
}
```

What I would like to get is that it leaves all values except the last one since it is one unique group (group1 == C) and 0.9 < 1. So I'd like to get the exact same data frame here except that 0.9 is replaced with NA. Moreover, would it be possible to just use if instead of ifelse?

Comment: If you want to replace in the original dataset 1) you have to assign the output back to `df` i.e. `df <- df %>%..` or use the magrittr `%<>%` operator.  2) I assume that you are only interested in the values in 'group1' that are also `uniq[1]` needs to be replaced.  In that case `df <- df %>% mutate(values = ifelse(sum(values) <1 & group1==uniq[1], 2, NA))`

Comment: Hmm... Thank you for the reply. However, if I use your first attempt, it applies the condition to the whole data set and not only to the subset where group1 ==  uniq[1]. The second approach just overwrites df with the altered values for group == uniq[1] (but allt he other rows are gone).

Comment: Then, I dont kknow what you are talking about.  Without a reproducible example and expected output, it is not easy

Comment: Sorry - you are totally right. I will upload one!

Answer (score 1):

dplyr won't create a new object unless you use an assignment operator (`<-`).

Compare

```
require(dplyr)
data(mtcars)

mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 4)
```

with

```
mtcars4 <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 4)
mtcars4
```

The data are the same, but in the second example the filtered data is stored in a new object `mtcars4`